# Drag and Drop File using Filedrop HTML 5 Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I have this simple code for drag and drop a file into a webpage but it's not working! The drop zone should change background color when I drag a file on it but it doesn't! Can you tell me why? Thank you.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.filedrop.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#dropZone {
    background: gray;
    border: black dashed 3px;
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#dropZone').filedrop({
        url: '@Url.Action("UploadFiles")',
        paramname: 'files',
        maxFiles: 5,
        dragOver: function () {
            $('#dropZone').css('background', 'blue');
        },
        dragLeave: function () {
            $('#dropZone').css('background', 'gray');
        },
        drop: function () {
            $('#dropZone').css('background', 'gray');
        },
        afterAll: function () {
            $('#dropZone').html('The file(s) have been uploaded successfully!');
        },
        uploadFinished: function (i, file, response, time) {
            $('#uploadResult').append('<li>' + file.name + '</li>');
        }
    });
});
</script>
<h2>File Drag & Drop Upload</h2>
<div id="dropZone">Drop your files here</div>
<br>
Uploaded Files:
<ul id="uploadResult">        
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you provide a live example? also what browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome latest version.

Comment: According to the code, when I drag a file over, it should turn to blue but it's not working. It's like there is no drag and drop functions. I just have a grey rectangle on the page!

Comment: Hmm... seems to work here. http://jsfiddle.net/6bn3K/

Comment: Can you add fallback_id for example? I do not know how can I upload files on click (for mobile)

Answer (score 0):

You should add `Fallback_id`

Something like below:

```js
$('#dropZone').filedrop({
  url: '@Url.Action("UploadFiles")',
  fallback_id:'test'
});
```

This `fallback_id` is Id of input `type=file`